# Adding a comma to split numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a fancy number box. The below is a function that when people finishing loading there ll be a number box count up to the result:

```
function countUp(count){
                    var div_by = 100,
                        speed = Math.round(count/div_by),
                        $display = $('.count'),// i bind the function to the class count
                        run_count = 1,
                        int_speed = 24;

                    var int = setInterval(function() {
                        if(run_count < div_by){
                            $display.text(speed * run_count);
                            run_count++;
                        } else if(parseInt($display.text()) < count) {
                            var curr_count = parseInt($display.text()) + 1;
                            $display.text(curr_count);
                        } else {
                            clearInterval(int);
                        }
                    }, int_speed);
                }
                countUp(6435);
```

It's working fine by i'd like to add comma to split the thousand like 6,345
I tried to convert the result using `toString()` but it doesn't work

```
countUp(6435).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

Comment: Try replacing using this regex - `.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use toLocaleString method

```
countUp(6435).toLocaleString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this one:

```
var num = countUp(6435);
num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```